# How to override bootstrap styles in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have declared styles in angular.json file section:

```
  "styles": ["src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css", "src/assets/css/style.css"]
```

First I have added `bootstrap.min.css`, then custom `style.css`.

`Style.css` should override bootstap styles, but this does not happen.

How to be?

Comment: Are you sure the spelling is correct? It might be styles.css

Comment: If you inspect an element in the dev console you should see where the styles are being applied from. Are only the bootstrap styles there or can you also see your custom styles being overwritten?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, it works, but not overrides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For production mode, try:

```
ng build --prod -extract-css false
```

See [**Angular cli changes css files order when build**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9475)